# Editar datos de una tabla sql en una tabla en html

Tags: php, sql, web, xampp

Solo tengo una duda. Pero antes, gracias por la ayuda en la pregunta anterior.

Hay una forma de editar los datos sql en una tabla html? Ya logre hacer que aparezcan, lo que quiero hacer ahora es que sean editables y los cambios se vean en la base de datos.

Mi codigo:

```
<table id="tablaprofesores" name="tablaprofesores">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Nombre del profesor</td>
            <td>Materia que da</td>
            <td>Fecha de clase</td>
            <td>Hora de inicio</td>
            <td>Hora de finzalizacion</td>
            <td>Numero de computadores</td>
            <td>Comandos</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reservacdt LIMIT 10";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nombre']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['materia']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['fecha']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['fechaemp']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['fechater']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['numero']?></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="cambiar" name="cambiar" value="Cambiar datos"></input></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update:

Decidi hacer este metodo que me enseñaron una vez, por alguna razon no funciona correctamente.

```
<table id="tablaprofesores" name="tablaprofesores">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Nombre del profesor</td>
            <td>Materia que da</td>
            <td>Fecha de clase</td>
            <td>Hora de inicio</td>
            <td>Hora de finzalizacion</td>
            <td>Numero de computadores</td>
            <td>Comandos</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php //Se crea la conexion a la base de datos
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reservadiseno LIMIT 10";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                <td id="nombre_row"><?php echo $row['nombre']?></td>
                <td id="materia_row"><?php echo $row['materia']?></td>
                <td id="fecha_row"><?php echo $row['fecha']?></td>
                <td id="fechaemp_row"><?php echo $row['fechaemp']?></td>
                <td id="fechater_row"><?php echo $row['fechater']?></td>
                <td id="numero_row"><?php echo $row['numero']?></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="cambiar" name="cambiar" value="Cambiar datos" onclick="cambiar('.$row.')"></input></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="salvar" name="salvar" value="Salvar datos" onclick="salvar('.$row.')"></input></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }

        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<script> <!-- Scripts a usar -->

function cargartabla(){ //Esto carga la tabla cuando se edita
for(i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("salvar").length; i++){
 document.getElementsByName("salvar").item(i).hidden=true;
}
}

function cambiar(no)
{
 document.getElementsByName("cambiar").item(no).hidden=true;
 document.getElementsByName("salvar").item(no).hidden=false;

var job=document.getElementById("nombre_row"+no);
var email=document.getElementById("materia_row"+no);
var user=document.getElementById("fecha_row"+no);
var estado=document.getElementById("fechaemp_row"+no);
var estado=document.getElementById("fechater_row"+no);
var estado=document.getElementById("numero_row"+no);

var nombre_data=nombre.innerHTML;
var materia_data=materia.innerHTML;
var fecha_data=fecha.innerHTML;
var fechaemp_data=fechaemp.innerHTML;
var fechaeter_data=fechater.innerHTML;
var numero_data=numero.innerHTML;

nombre.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='nombre_text"+no+"'value='"+nombre_data+"'>";
materia.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='materia_text"+no+"' value='"+materia_data+"'>";
fecha.innerHTML="<input type='date' id='fecha_text"+no+"' value='"+fecha_data+"'>";
fechaemp.innerHTML="<input type='time' id='fechaemp_text"+no+"' value='"+fechaemp_data+"'>";
fechater.innerHTML="<input type='time' id='fechater_text"+no+"' value='"+fechater_data+"'>";
numero.innerHTML="<input type='number' id='numero_text"+no+"' value='"+numero_data+"'>";
document.getElementsByName("salvar").item(i).hidden=false;
}

function salvar(no)
{
var nombre_val=document.getElementById("nombre_text"+no).value;
var materia_val=document.getElementById("materia_text"+no).value;
var fecha_val=document.getElementById("fecha_text"+no).value;
var fechaemp_val=document.getElementById("fechaemp_text"+no).value;
var fechater_val=document.getElementById("fechater_text"+no).value;
var numero_val=document.getElementById("numero_text"+no).value;

document.getElementById("nombre_row"+no).innerHTML=nombre_val;
document.getElementById("materia_row"+no).innerHTML=materia_val;
document.getElementById("fecha_row"+no).innerHTML=fecha_val;
document.getElementById("fechaemp_row"+no).innerHTML=fechaemp_val;
document.getElementById("fechater_row"+no).innerHTML=fechater_val;
document.getElementById("numero_row"+no).innerHTML=numero_val;

document.getElementsByName("cambiar").item(no).hidden=false;
document.getElementsByName("salvar").item(no).hidden=true;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es amplia, esto podría lograrse de diferentes manera, te recomiendo ver algún curso completo de php en youtube. Recomendaría PildorasInformaticas te ensenara todo eso y mas.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaron existen muchas maneras de hacerlo, pero ya que estas mostrando la info en una tabla podrias agregar otra columna y en esa permites poder editar. Asi tendrias como un pequeño CRUD.

Ejemplo:

```
<td><a href="vistanueva.html?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" EDITAR </a></td>
```

Así creas una vista con ese nombre y realizas la consulta nuevamente pero esta vez solamente por el ID que pasas por el href.En la nueva vista cargas los dos datos en input y ya podrías editar/guardar la informacion.

Lo que te muestro de html es un ejemplo para que te guies y ya tengas una idea de que tendrías que hacer. Exito!

Answer (score 0):

la solución que te recomiendo es, que cada fila tenga un botón de edición con una id donde puedas relacionar con la id del registro que tienes, en caso de que el botón sea pulsado haces un update en la base de datos de la manera que mas te guste.